# How to stop file api request in react-pdf library

Tags: react-pdf

I am trying to avoid making a call to API to fetch pdf file that is already requested during the same user session in the react application, can someone please help me how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Possibly set a state tracking whether the user has made a request?